# How do I get the Search Term rewrite URL?

Tags: magento

I want to get the variable text of the Search Term rewrite URL as shown in the picture below:
[image]

How do I get this text in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->load(1)->getRedirect();
```

where 1 is the ID of the Catalog Search entry.